# Cucumber tags for scenario outline examples

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, integration-testing

In the project I am currently working we are using cucumber for integration testing and to keep the regular daily builds from getting too big we use profiles using tags to have a smaller daily test and a larger weekly build test suite.

Now I have a scenario outline with example inputs that I want to split up so that one example is in the daily build and others in the weekly.

Something in the spirit of

```
Scenario Outline: Doing some tests
  Given a step
  When I do some <input>
  Then I should get some <output>

Examples:
  |input     |output    |
  @daily
  |daily 1   |daily 2 o |
  @weekly
  |week 1    |week 1 o  |
  |week 2    |week 3 o  |
      .           .
      .           .     
      .           .
  |week 999  |week 999 o|
```

Is this possible in any way? Should it be? Or is it a dumb idea to do it this way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After some research I found out that this is already supported from out of the box. You just have to add two Example headers to the test. Using my own example from the question to illustrate

```
Scenario Outline: Doing some tests
  Given a step
  When I do some <input>
  Then I should get some <output>

@daily
Examples:
  |input     |output    |
  |daily 1   |daily 2 o |

@weekly
Examples:
  |input     |output    |
  |week 1    |week 1 o  |
  |week 2    |week 3 o  |
      .           .
      .           .     
      .           .
  |week 999  |week 999 o|
```

Comment: An awkwardness: this is pretty great, but it seems that hooks (i.e. `Before('@tag')` and `After('@tag')` are not run when tags are applied in the examples block.

Comment: Not working in the current version 4.2.6 Cucumber - Java

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been fixed, and if so, it what release of the library, Scenario Outlines are extremely useful, but not being able to accomplish tagged hooks on them is disappointing.

Comment: Does it supported by pytest-bdd , it not working for me , I invoked the test like 'pytest -k "daiily" ' . any changes required for pytest-bdd ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Before hook for an Example? It doesn't work for me, it may be a bug or feature.

```
    Scenario Outline: Doing some tests
    Given a step
    When I do some <input>
    Then I should get some <output>

    @daily
    Examples:
    |input     |output    |
    |daily 1   |daily 2 o |

    Before('@daily') do
     p "before daily"
    end
```

Nothing happens. It seems that cucumber doesn't know about Before examples. Using Ruby Cucumber 1.3.10

Comment: ran into the same issue. Has this been resolved. If so, what java release of cucumber/jvm ? thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm sitting in a debugger, in an 'after scenario' hook, with 'scenario' showing as a Cucumber:Ast:OutlineTable::ExampleRow and 'scenario.source_tag_names' returns the feature tags and the scenario outline tags.

Rooting around in the object directly, although I can easily find the table and cells references, I can't even locate the example table's tags by force.

We're successfully using tags on the example tables to filter them in and out (per the accepted answer), so Cucumber obviously sees them for that purpose, but that's all those tags appear to be available for - not for hooks, and not for observing from hooks.

Seems a bit inconsistent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible partial workaround with [data tables](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#data-tables):

```
Scenario: Doing some tests
Given a step
When I do some input
 |env   | input  |
 |daily | daily 1|
 |weekly| week 1 |
 |weekly| week 2 |
Then I should get some output
 |env   | output   |
 |daily | daily 1 o|
 |weekly| week 1 o |
 |weekly| week 2 o |
```

In your code, you get the table data object and there you can check what environment is it right now, and what data to use.
But multiple tests (like week1 week2) should be then implemented in code.
In this case, it will be hard :/

But maybe the workaround will be useful in other cases.